# Should I provide a full or partial image to glTexSubImage2D?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a piece of `GLvoid* data` that contains an entire image, which is periodically updated throughout my program. I use `glTexImage2D` to initialize a texture on the GPU with this data.

I would like to use `glTexSubImage2D` to update parts of the texture as necessary. The [documentation for glTexSubImage2D](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexSubImage2D.xhtml) describes the `GLvoid* pixels` argument as such:

> Specifies a pointer to the image data in memory.

What "image data" is this expecting? Can I provide the entire `GLvoid* data`, or is it expecting a buffer that *only* contains the data being copied?

If it expects the partial data, is there an alternative way to provide the whole buffer instead?

Comment: It's the other way around: `glTexSubImage2D` isn't used to update a part of a texture in GPU memory, it is used to upload part of an image data buffer to the GPU memory.

Comment: Would glPixelStore's GL_PACK_ROW_LENGTH solve the problem? (and to a lesser extent GL_PACK_SKIP_PIXELS and GL_PACK_SKIP_ROWS). Haven't dug too deep myself, hence a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide entire image data with call

```
glTexSubImage2D( target, level, 0, 0, W, H, format, type, pixels);
```

W and H are texture width and height, the whole texture will be copied, pixels is W*H array. Or you can provide only modified data with call

```
glTexSubImage2D( target, level, offset_x, offset_y, w, h, format, type, pixels);
```

where w and h is weigth and height of modified data so offset_x + w < W and offset_y + y < Y. pixels is w*h array.

Edit:

```
glPixelStorei( GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, W);
glPixelStorei( GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, offset_x);
glPixelStorei( GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, offset_y);

glTexSubImage2D( target, level, offset_x, offset_y, w, h, format, type, pixels);
```

where pixels is W*H

Comment: In your latter example, then, `pixels` should only contain the modified data? Is there a way to pass the entire image instead, and let this function "cherry-pick" the modified data?

Comment: Yes. In second example pixels contains only modified data with size w*h , w <= W and h <=H. You can pass entire image using [glPixelStoref](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLAPI/glPixelStore)

Comment: GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS and GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS will help, but you still need to call glTexSubImage2D

Answer (score 2):

It's only the data to be copied. Or you will have to waste a lot of memory to upload only a part of the image(sometimes the only part you currently have).

P.S. And it's rather painful that it doesn't even support strided data. So if you have a full image, you can't upload left or right half of it without copying it to a smaller buffer.

Comment: As mentioned in the question comments, would `glPixelStore` be any help here? Could it not be used to stride the data?